# Importing random number from different modules

Tags: python, module

I am new in python and I need your help in order to have a better understanding of how to use modules.

Suppose you have two modules `a.py` and `b.py`.

**`a.py`** has the following lines of code

```
import b
import random

a = random.random()
print(a)
```

and `b.py` haw the following lines of code:

```
b = random.random()
print(b)
```

However, when I run the code I get the following message:

`E0602:Undefined variable 'random'`

Is this an issue or this is logical?

Comment: You should `import random` in the `b` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is logical, since you did *not* define a variable named `random` in the `b.py` file. A module (like `b.py` has its own scope), so unless you reference a *builtin* variable, or you import a variable, the variable is not loaded.

This makes sense, since otherwise the import in another module could completely change the variables in another module. This would thus result in "unstable" implementations. Furthermore even if this would work (it does not, at least not without using some "hackish" functions that alter the importing procedure), you import `random` after you import `b`, so at the time you import `b`, you did not even loaded the `random` module anyway.

You thus can let this work with:

file **`a.py`**:

```
import b
import random

a = random.random()
print(a)
```

file **`b.py`**:

```
import random

b = random.random()
print(b)
```